# Space adjustment between <hr> line tag

Tags: html, css

I have a two `<p>` elements between a `<hr>` element.

I want to adjust the space between the line, however I'm not sure how to do that. This is because:

- Line height can't be negative
- margin-top / margin-bottom also do not work here.

It seems like a very simple task but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

How can I adjust these spaces between the `<hr>` for the top and bottom `<p>`?

https://jsfiddle.net/pLput9w3/

```
<p>Hello</p>
<hr>
<p>Hello from the other side</p>
```

Comment: A negative `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` will work: https://jsfiddle.net/nuqg7ors/1/

Answer (score 3):

Just like the comment suggested, you could try negative margins which should work fine in this case, if you don't want to change the margins of the `p` elements. But this would need to be changed for changes in `p` though

```css
hr {
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-bottom: -1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<hr>
<p>Hello from the other side</p>
```

Another way would be to remove the default margins of the `p` and `hr`

```css
p, hr {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<hr>
<p>Hello from the other side</p>
```

Also, you can simply remove the `hr` and instead use a `border` on the second `p`

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}


.top-border {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p class="top-border">Hello from the other side</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the margin on both the `hr` element and the `p` element.

```
hr {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
p {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```